# String Replace Three Characters in a Row

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, replace, str-replace

What I have is `"text - something else`", now with the below code I can convert it to `"text-something-else"`, but I'm unhappy with the extra replace.

Is there anyway to merge each into one line?

**PHP:**

```
$url = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", splitstring($item->item)));
$url = str_replace("---", "-", $url);
```

**JS:**

```
title = title.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
title = title.replace(/---/g, '-');
```

The latter replaces prevent this: `"text---something-else"`, so they're needed.

Comment: you can use php's trim() to remove the whitespace, not sure about js.

Comment: Why are you unhappy in an extra line of code?

Comment: @Tivie feels dirty, and I'm curious to know if there is a better solution.

Comment: @Chaplin Ah... the "beautiful code" syndrome. =P I feel you bro. Most of us suffer from that. pebbl answer seems a smart answer, although str_replace is usually faster than preg_replace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the power of regular expressions:

```
preg_replace('/[ -]+/', '-', $str);
```

or:

```
str.replace(/[ -]+/g, '-');
```

The above will obviously replace any number of hyphens or spaces with a singular hyphen, which is slightly different from your previous logic. If you wish to take into account any other characters you can easily do the following:

```
/[\s_-]+/
```

The above will match any white space, hyphen or underscore.

As a word of warning when using a hyphen in your regular expression you should make sure it is at the end of the `[bracketed]` group i.e. `[abc-]` or you will need to escape it using a backslash, like `[a\-bc]`. This is because regular expression syntax allows you to match ranges such as `0-9` which will not be what you intend in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try (I haven't tested it):

```
// php
$what_to_replace = array(" - ", " ");

// should process " - " first, so spaces around "-" should not be replaced twice
$url = strtolower(str_replace($what_to_replace, "-", splitstring($item->item)));
```

see [examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: @Dinesh Are you sure? .. from original text "text - something else" I wanted to replace " - " with "-" and then space between "something else" also replace with "-" to get "text-something-else"

Comment: i think he was only concern with 2 things replace space and triple dash.. if he wants to replace more he can add them into array.. anyways he liked the regular expression answer..